# Yes/No Loop with multiple questions

Tags: excel, vba, loops

The question asks to create a loop asking an initial yes/no question: are you saving for college? If no, the loop should end. If Yes, the code should ask the user to answer: Years until college starts, annual college payment, and another child? If the answer for another child is yes, the loop should start over. If the answer is no, the loops should end. I am having trouble putting the pieces together.

I have tried using yes/no message boxes but run into the issue of changing to numerical answers and getting the loop to start over.

```
Ans = MsgBox("Saving for college?", vbYesNo)
If Ans = vbNo Then Exit Sub
If Ans = vbYes Then
Dim myvalue As Integer
myvalue = InputBox("Years until college starts?")
Dim value As Integer
value = InputBox("Annual College Payments?")
Ans = MsgBox("Another child?")
Ans = MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo)
If Ans = vbYes**strong text** Then
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Questions()

    Dim ans As Long
    Dim yearsToCollegeStart As String, annualCollegePayment As String

    Do
        If MsgBox("Saving for college", vbYesNo + vbQuestion) = vbNo Then Exit Sub

        yearsToCollegeStart = InputBox("Years until college starts?")
        annualCollegePayment = InputBox("Annual College Payments?")

        ans = MsgBox("Another child", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
    Loop while ans = vbYes

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful.

Comment: You are welcome but did it solve the question? If no, why?

Answer (score 0):

The below code may help you. However have in mind that you have to handle user answers (yes, no, close, cancel) in both message boxes & inputboxes.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim Ans1 As Long, value1 As String, value2 As String, Ans2 As String

    Ans1 = MsgBox("Saving for college", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)

    If Ans1 = vbNo Then
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf Ans1 = vbYes Then

        value1 = InputBox("Years until college starts?")
        value2 = InputBox("Annual College Payments?")
        Ans2 = MsgBox("Another child", vbYesNo + vbQuestion)
        If Ans2 = vbYes Then
            'Code
        ElseIf Ans2 = vbNo Then
            'Code
        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, this is helpful

Comment: Glad to hear that i help. If you find my answer helpful please vote it to help others with the same issue